# Navigation controller is not working in multiple storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

I have a login page a the beginning of my app. when user is granted I'll redirect it to another storyboard.

In this below photo1: the white screen check is user granted or not. if yes I'll redirect the to Photo2. else I'll redirect them to the login page ( red pages in photo1).)

[image]

In below Photo2:(I'll show a table view which contains some data. when the user clicks one of them, it goes to the next page (right one).)

[image]

And Photo3 is just to clarify Photo2.

[image]

The problem is Photo2 after a user clicked a row in the table view. the back button does not work (it is visible in the app)

**The code below shows the white screen's code in Photo1:**

```
 if let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: ConstantsKey.token){
            if !token.isEmpty{
                let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainTabBar", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarVC")
                let rootController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                rootController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(red: 229/255, green: 28/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1)
                self.present(rootController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }else{
//              let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

                let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVc")

                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }else{
            let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVc")
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }
```

**The code below shows the  login page after the user is granted:**

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainTabBar", bundle: nil)
                        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarVC")
                        let rootController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                        self.present(rootController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**The code below shows the way I redirect the user to the page which has the problem in the photo 2:**

```
let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:  "ShopVc") as! ShopViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next, animated: true)
```

**I Also have added the code below to Delegate :**

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Am I doing something wrong here which might cause this problem?

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
***ANSEWER***
I created a new project which works fine there! I think it was the xCode's problem!

Comment: this line `let next = ` is missing the type at the end...

Comment: Thank for reporting that, I fixed it in question

Comment: Are you presenting the view controller on tableview cell clicked

Comment: @V_rohit what do you mean? when the user clicks a row randomly, I want to go to another VC

Comment: then use did select method of tableview if you want to go to next view controller

Comment: @V_rohit I don't have the problem with that! my problem is when a user is clicked the row and I have redirected him/her to the next page the back button is not working

Comment: OHkk... So your problem is going back to previous view controller

Comment: @V_rohit that's right. even the the button is visible but it is not clickable

Comment: put the breakpoint on it check it is working on not and show your tableview code and button action method

Comment: my tableview is working and presenting the data, even i click it i goes to the next page and even that page works fine, but navigationbar is not working

Comment: would you upload it on GitHub?

Comment: all the data is on local host

Comment: there is no need of data here its something you are missing in your code

Comment: https://github.com/AmirFT/small-office

Comment: my project starts with Main Storyboard, as soon as change it to start with MainTabBar Storyboard, the back button start working

Comment: @ItanHant I think the issue is you are presenting the view , try push to view controller .

Comment: where? in which file? could you be more specific

Comment: @ItanHant when you move to next screen try to use pushviewcontroller instead of present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

restart your project , this could be an Xcode problem